# Terraform plan shows changes for CanonicalUser that are already applied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudfront

I have an IAM policy to allow my CloudFront to read and list objects in my S3 bucket specified as follows:

```
[...]

Effect = "Allow"
    Principal = {
      "CanonicalUser" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
    Action : [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket"
    ],

[...]
```

With this **already applied**, any time I run again `terraform plan` changes appear with regards to that `Principal` / `CanonicalUser` which is pretty inconvenient as blurs the rest of the output.

Any solution to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it replacing in the terraform configuration the `CanonicalUser` by a `AWS` type identifier:

So my policy above will be instead:

```
Principal = {
    "AWS" : arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
}
```

With this the plan shows no changes when nothing has changed